# registration/login button stop and lag

Tags: android

I keep coming past the same issue I copied the code from :

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

I thought that I had no issues, but when I try to register or sign it the app lags for a min and then stops. Can you explain how to fix the issue and what exactly the issue is?

```
my log cat 
11-20 15:57:45.821: I/dalvikvm(965): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-20 15:57:45.851: I/dalvikvm(965): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's not clear what your question is. I'd suggesting adding more context of your issue and phrasing a clear question to attract answers. Also, adding more relevant tags helps draw more attention to your question.

Comment: alright thanks going to keep that in mind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have read the code, and i found the possible issues
1. Code dont checks if theres an active internet connection.
2. Have you your own server? If so, is it working correctly?
Check it by using tools like : Advanced REST Client (add-on for firefox)
3. Downloading code is executing on UI thread -> pauses all animations and screen refresh until the downloading gets to the end.

I cant give more informations -> i tried to point you to a good direction in solving this problem.
Please be more specific, thats the best answer i could give.

Comment: i don't think that was me @Toumash

Comment: I know :) Is my answer useful?

Comment: yeah kinda... i realize it has to be an issue with my phph cause i just tried testing the code online in php testers and there all getting errors. do u by chance have a good forum or link for understanding php errors

Comment: Just search the stackOverflow :) and if the answer was helpful accept it